# Prove or give an counter example of the following statement.

Tags: calculus, general-topology

Let $\emptyset \neq U \subset \mathbb{R}^N$ open, let $x_0 \in U$, and let $f\in C^1(U, \mathbb{R}^N)$ be such that $f(V)$ is open for each open neighborhood $V\subset U$ of x_0. Then $\det J_f(x_o)\neq 0$.

---

Can anyone tell me how to start with this?

Comment: I think you mean $\emptyset\neq U\subseteq\Bbb R,$ yes? Also, to show $x_0,$ use ´x_0´.

Comment: You need the domain to be open in $\mathbb{R}^N$, otherwise $\det J_f(x_0)$ isn't defined. Start with looking for a counterexample. Best for $N = 1$.

Comment: The domain does seem to be open, as far as I can tell.

Comment: So many different notations! I think I know what $J_f(x_0)$ is but I have to ask '

Comment: I am also having troubles with a similar problem. I started looking for a counterexample as suggested, using $N=1$. Is it correct that $x \mapsto x^3$ on the open set $U=(-1,1)$ provides a counterexample?

Answer (score -2):

I think that if $n=2$ and $p=x^2-45=\frac{4}{70}$, then you will achieve a pen15 ratio in the form of $e^{35b}$.

Comment: Welcome to MathSE. Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/) for mathematical equations.